# Nest Token revoked but api does not returns "401 unauthorized" response

Tags: php, nest-api

I'm building an app using the nest api. We can successfully authorize a user with the API, however, if the users revokes the app authorization from within it's account, the API does not return a 401 unauthorized response but the full response as if the user had not revoked the token access.

Here's a step by step of how I tested :

First the user comes to our website, we request the auth url to nest

```
https://home.nest.com/login/oauth2?client_id=%s&state=%s
```

Where both string are replaced by, respectively, the product key and a random state string.

From there, the user can authorize the app, it will then redirect to the configured redirect url of the product.

We then query for a long access token, which we also get properly.

Then the user can ask to see a list of devices within his account (cameras only), so we query the users' devices list with

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
       CURLOPT_URL => "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices",
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
       CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
       CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
       CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
       CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
       CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
       CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
       CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
       CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
       CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => true,
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
         "authorization: Bearer ".$token,
         "content-type: application/json",
         "Cache-Control: no-cache"
       ),
     ));
```

Where $token is the users' long access oauth token.

This works just as expected. Until the user revokes the app authorization from within his nest account. If we follow the API documentation, this call would return a 401 Unauthorized response.

However, the response is still the list of users' devices, even if the token is now invalid. Which mean we still have access to the user's informations even if he technically revoked our access. The user is therefore never prompted to re-authorize the application and since this is taking place directly in the nest website and that there are no event callback, we can't detect if the user wants to revoke the rights of our application.

This is causing us quite a few headaches as we can't test the functionality of our website properly. Ideally, we would then have to request another token from the user.

Thanks

Comment: Could you check if this is still reproducible?

Comment: It looks like it has beed fixed!